# Java 2D Array - Detect Duplicate Values

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, repeat

What is the easiest/simplest/most efficient way to detect if a 2D array has duplicate/repeating values?

e.g. 2D Array:

```
{{2, 17, 4, 5} {3, 2, 34 9}}
```

This matrix has multiple "2" values.

I want to set a boolean to true if this is the case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm aware that I can probably loop through the entire matrix for each number but that is like 4 loop statements. Seems inefficient to me.

Comment: Can you say something more about data in your array? Can one row contain duplicate values like `{2,3,2,1}`?

Comment: No. No duplicates at all in the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best you can do here is O(n) because you won't know if the very last element is a duplicate until you check it.  Here's an idea:

Have a `Set` of values.  Iterate the 2d array and for each element do this:

```
if (!set.add(element))
   // a duplicate was found!
```

This works because [Set.add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29) returns "true if this set did not already contain the specified element"

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient with a `Set`? `if (set.contains(value))` then there's a duplicate, otherwise add the value to the set. (The fact that the standard HashSet implementation use an underlying HashMap is another matter...)

Comment: I'm a little confused where you got the "1". And it seems nice, but my issue is this is a "lab" for school so it has to use a 2D array.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Yeah good point.  That's a better solution

Comment: @Connor You will have to loop through the array in one way or another. Our suggestion is that you add each value you encounter to a HashSet if it doesn't already exists in it - if it already exists in the set, well then you have found a duplicate.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg updated.  My brain went to `Map` first because I was reminded of a similar interview question I asked where someone asked the quickest way to get the *number of duplicates*.  A `Set` doesn't help with that.